# Using mysql to pull 1 of 8 columns based on which checkbox/radio button is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting very close to having this website functioning correctly. I found a solution to my last question with some help from the great people on this site and have one last question. I have 8 `input` fields on my site that will pull agents information based on which expertise is selected. This would most likely be a lot easier if the database was set up differently but I can't change the database's structure.

[Live version of the site](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/advance.php)

My database structure:

```
ID | MemberID | First_Name | Last_Name | Ancillary | LongTerm | Medicare |  ETC..<br />
 1 | 77777    | John       | Doe       | 1         | 1        | 0        | ETC..
```

Now I need to pull the information based on which expertise is selected by the user.
Since my expertise areas are a column each, and their value is 1 for yes and 0 for no, has to be what makes it a little more complicated for a novice programmer.

HTML that is used to pull according to which value is selected:

```
<label for="agent">Agent Expertise</label><br />
<label for="ancillary"><input type="radio" value="Ancillary" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="ancillary" />Ancillary</label><br />
<label for="smallgroup"><input type="radio" value="Smallgroup" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="smallgroup" />Small Group</label><br />
<label for="largegroup"><input type="radio" value="LargeGroup" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="largegroup" />Large Group</label><br />
<label for="medicare"><input type="radio" value="Medicare" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="medicare" />Medicare</label><br />
<label for="longterm"><input type="radio" value="LongTerm" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="longterm" />Long Term Care</label><br />
<label for="individual"><input type="radio" value="Individual" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="individual" />Individual Plan</label><br />
<label for="tpa"><input type="radio" value="TPASelfInsured" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="tpa" />TPA Self Insured</label><br />
<label for="ppaca"><input type="radio" value="CertifiedForPPACA" onChange="showUser(this.value)" name="expertise[]" id="ppaca" />Certified for PPACA</label><br />
```

jQuery I used to pull the information and post into the div using ajax:

**Updated my jQuery and AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input').on('click', function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: ({expertise: value}),
                url: "expertise.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#bodyA').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Now the sql is where I am having trouble:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `roster` WHERE Ancillary = '1' OR SmallGroup = '1' OR IndividualPlans = '1' OR LongTermCare = '1' OR Medicare = '1' OR LargeGroup = '1' OR TPASelfInsured = '1' OR CertifiedForPPACA = '1' ORDER BY Last_Name ASC";
```

When I use OR it calls everyone in the database but when I use AND it calls only the agents that have every expertise. (AND makes sense to me) 
PHP file:

```
include 'datalogin.php'; // PHP File to login credentials

        $sql="SELECT * FROM `roster` WHERE Ancillary = '1' OR SmallGroup = '1' OR IndividualPlans = '1' OR LongTermCare = '1' OR Medicare = '1' OR LargeGroup = '1' OR TPASelfInsured = '1' OR CertifiedForPPACA = '1' ORDER BY Last_Name ASC";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) // Connects to database
            or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

            echo "<h1>" . "Find a Local OAHU Agent." . "</h1>";

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // Gets results from the database
                echo "<div class='agentcon'>" . "<span class='agentn'>" . "<strong>".$row['First_Name'] . "&nbsp;" .$row['Last_Name'] . "</strong>" . "</span>" . "<a href=mailto:".$row['Email'] . ">" . "<span class='email'>" . "Send an e-mail to" . "&nbsp;" .$row['First_Name'] . "</span>" . "</a>" ."<div class='floathr'></div>";
                if ($row['Company'] == NULL) {
                    echo "<p>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<p>" . "<strong>" .$row['Company'] . "</strong>" . "<br>";
                }
                echo $row['WorkAddress1'] . "&nbsp;" .$row['WorkCity'] . "," . "&nbsp;" .$row['WorkStateProvince'] . "&nbsp;" .$row['WorkZipCode'] . "<br>";
                if ($row['Work_Phone'] !== NULL) {
                    echo "<strong>" . "Work" . "&nbsp;" . "</strong>" .$row['Work_Phone'] . "<br>";
                }
                if ($row['Fax'] !== NULL) {
                    echo "<strong>" . "Fax" . "&nbsp;" . "</strong>" .$row['Fax'] . "<br>";
                }
                echo "<strong>" . "Agent Expertise:" . "</strong>";
                if ($row['Ancillary'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "Ancillary" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['SmallGroup'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "Small Group" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['IndividualPlans'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "Individual Plans" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['LongTermCare'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "Long Term Care" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['Medicare'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "Medicare" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['LargeGroup'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "LargeGroup" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['TPASelfInsured'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "TPA Self Insured" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['CertifiedForPPACA'] == 1) {
                    echo "&nbsp;" . "Certified For PPACA";
                }
                echo "</p>" . "</div>";
            }

        mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: so do you want to get the agents that have all the areas selected or that have any of them? also what have you tried to relate the inputs of your form to your query?

Comment: You should add to your query name of selected radio like this:
`SELECT * FROM roster WHERE [radio_name_here] = 1`. That's it :)

Comment: I ended up making the `input` tags into a radial button so they can choose one option or another. (Ideally I would like it to be a checkbox and the user can choose one or multiple expertise to search for) I want it to pull up only the agents who have the expertise that the user selected. What I have tried was giving each `input` a `name="expertise[]"` and it's own `value=""` The form is also using the jQuery I wrote that uses ajax with it to process the php page based on the user input.

Comment: @IwoKucharski I gave that a try really hoping it would work but sadly it did now. :[ Here is what it says: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[expertise] = 1 ORDER BY Last_Name ASC' at line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on injection prevention but couldn't you implode your expertise like this.

The JQuery:

```
<script>
    function showUser(){
    $.post("expertise.php",$('#expertiseform').serialize(), function(data){$('#bodyA').html(data)});
return false;
}
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
      <form id="expertiseform" action="expertise.php" method="POST">
           <label for="agent">Agent Expertise</label><br />
           <label for="ancillary"><input type="checkbox" value="Ancillary" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="ancillary" />Ancillary</label><br />
           <label for="smallgroup"><input type="checkbox" value="Smallgroup" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="smallgroup" />Small Group</label><br />
           <label for="largegroup"><input type="checkbox" value="LargeGroup" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="largegroup" />Large Group</label><br />
           <label for="medicare"><input type="checkbox" value="Medicare" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="medicare" />Medicare</label><br />
           <label for="longterm"><input type="checkbox" value="LongTerm" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="longterm" />Long Term Care</label><br />
           <label for="individual"><input type="checkbox" value="Individual" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="individual" />Individual Plan</label><br />
           <label for="tpa"><input type="checkbox" value="TPASelfInsured" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="tpa" />TPA Self Insured</label><br />
           <label for="ppaca"><input type="checkbox" value="CertifiedForPPACA" onClick="showUser(this)" name="expertise[]" id="ppaca" />Certified for PPACA</label><br />
      </form>
```

The PHP:

```
    $poststr = $_POST['expertise']; //get our post data
if(is_array($poststr)){
if(count($poststr) > 1){ //count to make sure we have an array
    $expertise = implode(" AND ",$_POST['expertise']); //implode the array using AND as glue
}else{              //otherwise implode without glue
    $expertise = implode("",$poststr);
}
//here is our string for prepared statement
$sql = "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Company, WorkAddress1, WorkCity, WorkStateProvince, WorkZipCode, Work_Phone, Fax, Ancillary, SmallGroup, IndividualPlans, LongTermCare, Medicare, LargeGroup, TPASelfInsured, CertifiedForPPACA FROM roster WHERE ".$expertise." = 1";

if(!$stmt = $con->Prepare($sql))
{ 
    die; //echo error info if you want to know info

}else{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($First_Name, $Last_Name, $Email, $Company, $WorkAddress1, $WorkCity, $WorkStateProvince, $WorkZipCode, $Work_Phone, $Fax, $Ancillary, $SmallGroup, $IndividualPlans, $LongTermCare, $Medicare, $LargeGroup, $TPASelfInsured, $CertifiedForPPACA);
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($rows >0){
        echo "<h1>" . "Find a Local OAHU Agent." . "</h1>";
            while ($stmt->fetch()) { // Gets results from the database
            echo "<div class='agentcon'>" . "<span class='agentn'>" . "<strong>".$First_Name . "&nbsp;" .$Last_Name . "</strong>" . "</span>" . "<a href=mailto:".$Email . ">" . "<span class='email'>" . "Send an e-mail to" . "&nbsp;" .$First_Name . "</span>" . "</a>" ."<div class='floathr'></div>";
            if ($Company == NULL) {
                echo "<p>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<p>" . "<strong>" .$Company . "</strong>" . "<br>";
            }
            echo $WorkAddress1 . "&nbsp;" .$WorkCity . "," . "&nbsp;" .$WorkStateProvince . "&nbsp;" .$WorkZipCode . "<br>";
            if ($Work_Phone !== NULL) {
                echo "<strong>" . "Work" . "&nbsp;" . "</strong>" .$Work_Phone . "<br>";
            }
            if ($Fax !== NULL) {
                echo "<strong>" . "Fax" . "&nbsp;" . "</strong>" .$Fax . "<br>";
            }
                echo "<strong>" . "Agent Expertise:" . "</strong>";
            if ($Ancillary == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "Ancillary" . "/";
            }
            if ($SmallGroup == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "Small Group" . "/";
            }
            if ($IndividualPlans == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "Individual Plans" . "/";
            }
            if ($LongTermCare == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "Long Term Care" . "/";
            }
            if ($Medicare == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "Medicare" . "/";
            }
            if ($LargeGroup == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "LargeGroup" . "/";
            }
            if ($TPASelfInsured == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "TPA Self Insured" . "/";
            }
            if ($CertifiedForPPACA == 1) {
                echo "&nbsp;" . "Certified For PPACA";
            }
            echo "</p>" . "</div>";
        }
    $stmt->close;
    }else{
        Die;
    }
}
```

}

This all tested out ok on my server.

Comment: I am currently giving this a try and I had only a couple of errors so not to bad for a start. :p

Comment: I have had some bumps with this but I can't seem to find a way for it to pull the data. It is working error free and it may just be my jQuery/AJAX but I am really unsure at this point. Also sorry for the late response but I did not work until today.

Comment: Sorry I just logged in, are you still having issues with the script?

Comment: Yeah, sadly, I have put in 6 hours and still am at the same place as I was. I am almost positive that it is my jQuery that is not working correctly. I greatly appreciate showing me how to prevent sql injections but I just can't get it to pull any results. In Google Chrome's console it is loading the pag but not adding my variable to it.

Comment: Sorry deleted my erroneous comment "> 0" does work I messed up and put "> 1" which obviously caused the issue. Give me a few minutes and I will mock up your ajax and query.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: hey @JoshPowell the code above is fixed, sorry man there were several errors in it. Should work now, although I'm not a guru on AJAX and I am having problems getting the AJAX to work. I know this works by setting up a submit and form to check that its connecting, again check the $con and your table name.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, I am trying this right now and one error I am getting is with this line `$expertise = implode("",$poststr);`. I am going to do some research on implode because I have never used that before so let's hope I can figure something out!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help man. I had to alter a few things but I got everything working and pulling the correct fields. This project is finally done! lol For the `$expertise = implode("",$poststr);` I looked up what an implode is and it said the required value must be an array so I gave this `$expertise = implode("",array($poststr));` a try and it worked.

Comment: Sorry about the problems you were having, I'm glad it is working. My script was for checkboxes so it would return an array when posted. I finally got the code to work with AJAX and Checkboxes. I'm editing my answer with all the code I had on my mockup. :) from a friendly noob.

Comment: Ahh I see I see, I would ideally like it to be checkboxes so I'll give that try! No problem at all with the errors, if your not having errors somewhere during the development of a website then your doing it wrong or a god. Thanks a million and best of luck in the world of code!